# Filling values in a matrix from a loop in R

Tags: r

```
make_samps <- function (x) {   #function accepts length of sample
    samps <- matrix(1000, length(x))
    for (i in samps) a <- rnorm(x, 0, 1)
    samps[i,] = a
    print(samps)
}
```

Hello, I am quite new to R and I need some help with my function.

I am trying to create a matrix (I'm not sure if this is the right type of format) of 1000 data sets of length x (this should be able to be manipulated with the function) with a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1.

So basically I want to create a dataset of length x with mean=0 and sd=1 and repeat the action 1000 times and store the results so that further calculations can be made on the data sets.

I seem to be having trouble storing the created samples into my "samps" matrix when looping from 1-1000.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: `matrix(rnorm(5 * 1000, 0, 1), nrow = 5)`. The [`replicate`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) function may also be useful here. e.g. `replicate(1000, rnorm(5, 0, 1))` will return a 5 row by 1000 column matrix.

Comment: You need curly brackets so that the computer might know that the assignment is in the for loop ie: `for (i in samps) {a <- rnorm(x, 0, 1);
    samps[i,] = a}`. I had to place a semi colon since am writing on one line. But if you are writing same as above, you do not need semicolon. You just need the curly braces

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want each of your "data sets" to be one row in your matrix.

This can be done simply:

```
matrix(rnorm(1000*x), nrow=x)
```

The first argument for the constructor `matrix()` provides value for every cell in the matrix. You want a matrix with `x` rows and 1000 columns, so that's `1000*x` values, each generated from a normal distribution using `rnorm`. By providing `1000*x` values to the first argument specifying the number of rows, R is able to tell that you want a matrix of 1000 columns. Note that `mean=0` and `sd=1` are the defaults for `rnorm`.